# how to create a send file between shared folder in Windows 7 and Ubuntu-directory doesn't exist

Tags: windows-7, mount, ubuntu-12.04, samba, shared-folders

I am trying to create a shared folder between Ubuntu 12.04 server running on vmware and my Windows 7 desktop which is hosting it but I keep getting errors telling me that the directories do not exist and when I go to create them, they still tell me they don't exist. What I am hoping to do with these folders is to send system statistics such as vmstat to the shared folder so I can output them into excel, but the shared folders gives me lots of trouble. I have followed several tutorials on youtube and how to geek to no avail.

I have installed samba and changed my user path and settings as recommended on how to geek but it keeps mentioning mounting, whereas no other tutorials mention this at all-is it really necessary? it hasn't worked for me either.

the folder I am trying to share is called "sharedUbuntu" on my windows 7 desktop location and the workspace is called WORKSPACE and the computer name is \HP-LT. My ubuntu username is roryhbmc and the directory where I want to have my shared folder on ubuntu is /home/roryhbmc.

I even tried creating a shortcut using the ip address of my virtual machine but when I open it, it asks for my linux credentials(which are correct) but appears to want a windows password(my laptop has no password.)

All I want to do is to open a shared folder between Ubuntu and Windows which should not be so frustrating. I have already done the Windows part so would like help with the Linux. Does anyone know the syntax for setting it up in the command line on ubuntu? Keep in mind that I have already done samba and have set the settings to without root.

I was sent here from stack overflow as apparently it is "not programming related."